# Tensorflow segmentation fault running multirow tensor in C++ api

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, tensorflow, tensor

We are developing a method to load and run a .pb file within our code and have run into an odd segmentation fault which we cannot figure out how to debug.  See the following code:

```
extern "C" void run_graph_(char* path){

tensorflow::Status s;
tensorflow::GraphDef gdef;
s = tensorflow::ReadBinaryProto(tensorflow::Env::Default(), path, &gdef);
if (!s.ok()) 
{
    std::cout << "error: " << s.ToString() << "\n";     
}
else
{
    std::cout << "complete: " << s.ToString() << "\n"; 
}

for (int i = 0; i < gdef.node_size(); i++)
{
    if (gdef.node(i).name() == "nn_output" || gdef.node(i).name() == "nn_input")
        {
            gdef.node(i).PrintDebugString();
        }
    }

tensorflow::Session* session;
s = tensorflow::NewSession(tensorflow::SessionOptions(), &session);
s = session->Create(gdef);

std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;
tensorflow::Input::Initializer a({{8.81474371e-01,   8.90273631e-01,   1.72516504e-01, 5.55829580e-04,   9.59886648e-01,   1.20462446e-02, 1.98175483e-03,   1.38663768e-02}});
std::cout << a.tensor.DebugString() << std::endl;

std::cout << "run" << std::endl;
s = session->Run({{"nn_input", a.tensor}}, {"nn_output"}, {}, &outputs);
std::cout << "ran" << std::endl;
if (!s.ok()) 
{
    std::cout << "error: " << s.ToString() << "\n";     
}
if( outputs.size() > 0 )
{
    std::cout << "output: " << outputs[0].DebugString() << std::endl; // Tensor<type: float shape: [] values: 30>
}

// Free any resources used by the session
session->Close();
}
```

If we run this code, it works fine and we get the following output:

```
complete: OK
name: "nn_input"
op: "Placeholder"
attr {
  key: "dtype"
  value {
    type: DT_DOUBLE
  }
}
attr {
  key: "shape"
  value {
    shape {
      dim {
        size: -1
      }
      dim {
        size: 8
      }
    }
  }
}
name: "nn_output"
op: "Add"
input: "MatMul_4"
input: "Variable_4/read"
attr {
  key: "T"
  value {
    type: DT_DOUBLE
  }
}
Tensor<type: double shape: [1,8] values: [0.881474371 0.890273631 0.172516504]...>
run
ran
output: Tensor<type: double shape: [1,2] values: [0.016238948144062765 0.18446201154785777]>
```

However if we change the input tensor to have more than 1 row, for example:

```
tensorflow::Input::Initializer a({{8.81474371e-01,   8.90273631e-01,   1.72516504e-01, 5.55829580e-04,   9.59886648e-01,   1.20462446e-02, 1.98175483e-03,   1.38663768e-02}, {5.58892306e-01,   8.76436973e-01,   1.78063232e-01, 1.27910966e-01,   2.23700877e-01,   1.81518624e-01, 2.75920096e-01,   1.19812048e-02}, {3.69272573e-01,   6.75944584e-01,   8.35322158e-01, 3.89913301e-02,   4.26433973e-01,   2.94287142e-01, 1.08364415e-01,   3.93754220e-02}, {4.27477538e-01,   6.70533752e-01,   4.24946841e-02, 4.63300582e-02,   1.07105860e-02,   1.92844420e-02, 2.40294042e-02,   2.53449079e-03}, {2.66025541e-01,   9.75372575e-01,   6.53711732e-02, 7.52453239e-02,   2.75028037e-02,   1.23259054e-01, 1.29876045e-01,   1.75538941e-01}});
```

we get a seg fault when it tried to run the graph with the following output:

```
complete: OK
name: "nn_input"
op: "Placeholder"
attr {
  key: "dtype"
  value {
    type: DT_DOUBLE
  }
}
attr {
  key: "shape"
  value {
    shape {
      dim {
        size: -1
      }
      dim {
        size: 8
      }
    }
  }
}
name: "nn_output"
op: "Add"
input: "MatMul_4"
input: "Variable_4/read"
attr {
  key: "T"
  value {
    type: DT_DOUBLE
  }
}
Tensor<type: double shape: [5,8] values: [0.881474371 0.890273631 0.172516504]...>
run

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7fcd55f2f26f in ???
#1  0x7fcd5488b77a in ???
#2  0x7fcd548bebb3 in ???
#3  0x7fcd549032c3 in ???
#4  0x7fcd549204ef in ???
#5  0x7fcd52beccfc in ???
#6  0x7fcd52bbbcda in ???
#7  0x7fcd52bad633 in ???
#8  0x7fcd52818fc0 in ???
#9  0x7fcd52816d09 in ???
#10  0x7fcd5206706e in execute_native_thread_routine
        at ../../../.././libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc:83
#11  0x7fcd56d46e24 in ???
#12  0x7fcd55ff234c in ???
#13  0xffffffffffffffff in ???
Segmentation fault
```

We are using the C++ on CentOS 7.  I believe we should be able to run a multidimensional tensor through this graph as it works in python.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Compile with -g, use a debugger.

Comment: Which line in the C++ code does it crash on?

Comment: it fails somewhere inside the call to sess->Run we have that call bracketed by print statements "run" and "ran"

Comment: We either need enough information to reproduce the issue (i.e. code that generates a minimal GraphDef), or a stack trace from a debug build.

Comment: we fixed it... something was linked incorrectly with build of non debug version... we got the debug version to run and it ran fine, then recompiled the regular executable and we were ok